# cPanel email not receiving email from WordPress contact form

Tags: wordpress, email, smtp, cpanel

I have email account like support@example.com created on cpanel. This email account receiving all email from other domain (Gmail/Yahoo/Ebay etc) but not receiving from its own domain WordPress site contact form.

For example if I send email from Gmail support@example.com receiving, from other service like ebay, amazon or any other all email is receiving but when I am sending email using site contact form then email not receiving.

I have tested with WP Mail SMTP plugin, this plugin sending email to all other email account (Gmail/Yahoo/Hotmail) but not receiving its own domain email account.

FYI: My website and hosting and email hosting is not same. This problem is creating only on same domain.

Comment: If you are using remote email service, make sure that you have set "Remote Mail Exchanger". Edit MX entry for domain and set remote mail exchanger.

Comment: This is not really make any sense, my problem is not sending email, my wordpress installation sending email anywhere else like, gmail, yahoo, outlook, any other custom domain but not sending only its own domain email. Also if I want to set Remote Mail Exchanger where I will set that? I dont have any control panel there where my website is hosted, its using php sendmail for sending email.

Comment: The steps I provided to reslove this issue tosend email to own domain itself..If you don't understand there is nothing I can help you here.